# Проверка выполнения метода

Tags: c#, методы

Есть метод

```
    public void Send(int one, int two)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection("подключ."))
            {
                MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES ('one', 'two')", myCon);
                myCon.Open();
                upd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как проверить, что он выполнился (т.е.  данные добавились и соединение не оборвалось)?

Comment: ну так если было исключение - не выполнились

Comment: Допустим у меня есть еще один метод, который удаляет one и two, но выполнить его необходимо только в том случае, если one и two уже добавлены. То есть у меня только один вариант - положить его выполнение под upd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ? Или еще как то можно?

Comment: непонятна сама задача, возможно хватит просто изменения запроса

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html (на стороне БД) или проверить значение affected rows после первого запроса и выставить какой-нибудь флаг (на стороне C#)

Comment: `delete from NUMBERS where field1='one' and field2='two'` удалит только если one и two  уже добавлены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любое исключение произошедшее в `try` (к примеру недопустимое значение или отсутствие подключение)повлечет за собой иcисполнение кода из `catch`. В вашем случае это вывод ошибки...
Там где вы запускаете этот метод надо просто прописать тот же самый `try-catch`. При ошибке в использовании метода заработает код из `catch`

```
try{
send(int one, int two);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Заработался совсем) Спасибо!

Comment: C чего бы это помогло? Первый catch исключение проглотил и второму оно не достанется.

Comment: "второму оно не достанется" - какому второму? объясните пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду

Comment: @YuriGo, при том `catch`, который сейчас внутри `Send`, сам `Send` никогда не выбросит исключение, следовательно оборачивать его вызов в `catch` бесполезно.

Answer (score 3):

Убрать

```
catch(Exception ex)
```

и обработать нужное исключение там, где требуется проверить, выполнилось ли добавление.

Answer (score 0):

> Скажите пожалуйста, как проверить, что он выполнился (т.е. данные
>   добавились и соединение не оборвалось)?

По значению, которое возвращает метод `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

В конструкции `try-catch` неплохо было бы первым делом ловить исключения вроде `MySqlException`, т.к. если это будут проблемы с подключением (`Open()`), то сгенерирован будет именно этот тип исключения.

После того, как подключение установлено - оперируйте значениями `connection.State`, вроде удобно.

Соответственно код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
try
{
    send( .. , .. );
}
catch( MySqlException ex )
{
    // ...
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на задачу с другой стороны. Вы пытаетесь в C# решить задачу, которую должна решать БД. Заверните INSERT в явную транзакцию (в принципе это не обязательно, но и вреда не будет, всегда можно откатить изменения если что-то пошло не так. MySQL это умеет с 4.какой-то версии) и все это заверните в хранимую процедуру. От C# требуется только установить соединение, передать вызов процедуры и ее параметры. Для диагностики, что все прошло удачно, верните из хранимки число в качестве кода возврата и по нему узнавайте - правильно все прошло, или случилась какая-то ошибка. Не спорю, .NET вообще и C# в частности имеют хорошую поддержку операций в БД, но все таки задачи БД должна решать БД.

Comment: И любой из этих шагов всё равно может свалиться с исключением...

Comment: @Qwertiy может, причем по массе разных причин, я не предполагал отсутствие обработки исключений, но все таки такой вариант ИМХО немного более надежен, чем отправка голого запроса, да в случае изменений код процедуры поправить и отлпдить немного проще чем перекомпилировать клиент.

Comment: Это может быть сервером, а не клиентом.

Comment: @Qwertiy для БД он такой же клиент. Да и остановка сервера приложений для того чтобы поправить кривой запрос, тоже решение так себе, пользователи точно спасибо не скажут, хотя конечно все зависит, можно запилить обновленный релиз и перезапустить когда нет активных пользователей, если сервис не 24х7.

Comment: Обычно сервер с БД и само серверное приложение обновляются одновременно.

Comment: ну не знаю, у нас WCF-сервис обновляется когда появляется новый функционал, требующий изменений в сервисе, например при добавлении новой команды или изменениях в формате передаваемых данных, а в остальных случаях просто правим процедуры. Иногда от исходной процедуры остается только формат выходных данных и входные параметры, правда такие изменения, к счастью, бывают редко.